# как добавить колайдер к объекту добавленному через terrain/

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

на своей сцене я добавил деревья через инструмент terrainа(Paint trees). но я столкнулся с тем, что эти деревья не имеют коллизии, тогда я попробовал добавить к ним коллайдеры, но деревья все равно оставались без коллизии. как сделать их физическим объектом?

Comment: Terrain поддерживает только капсульный коллайдер на деревьях. Подробнее [тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/terrain-Trees.html)

Comment: спасибо огромное